# Python 2.7, what's the benefit of this kind of initialization in class?

Tags: python, class

```
class LogicGate(object):

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.label = n
        self.output = None # ????????????

    def getOutput(self):
        self.output = self.performGateLogic()
        return self.output

    def getLabel(self):
        return self.label

class BinaryGate(LogicGate):

    def __init__(self, n):  # ?????????????????
        LogicGate.__init__(self, n)

        self.pinA = None # ??????????????
        self.pinB = None # ??????????????

    def getPinA(self):
        return int(raw_input('Enter Pin A input for gate' + self.getLabel() + '-->'))

    def getPinB(self):
        return int(raw_input('Enter Pin A input for gate' + self.getLabel() + '-->'))

class UnaryGate(LogicGate):

    def __init__(self, n): # ??????????????
        LogicGate.__init__(self, n)

        self.pin = None # ?????????????

    def getPin(self):
        return int(raw_input('Enter Pin input for gate' + self.getLabel() + '-->'))

class AndGate(BinaryGate):

    def __init__(self, n): # ????????????
        BinaryGate.__init__(self, n)

    def performGateLogic(self):

        a = self.getPinA()
        b = self.getPinB()
        if a == 1 and b == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

This code belongs to Problem Solving with Algorithms and Date Structures.
When I remove the lines before the comment '# ????????', the code can run normally.
Why does the author write the code like this?
Whether is it a good code style?
Can I always remove these lines before the comment '# ????????' ?

Comment: It runs, both with and without those lines.

Comment: Consider a situation where you want to test whether or not you've got appropriate conditions to proceed (right before a very expensive operation).  `if self.pinA is None:`.

Comment: This looks like really poorly designed code, in my opinion. It's like Java conventions have been forced-fitted into Python.

Answer (score 1):

The author writes the code like that because it is good practice to never have uninitialised members and class parents, static checkers moan if you do.

The reason that it is not good practice is for future maintainability - let us say that the base class, `LogicGate`, was to gain a new property - say propagation_delay and a new method that allowed simulations to called `get_response_time` which relied on the current output state and the required, possibly new, state.  If all the code that was derived from that class did the correct initialisations then it would all work fine, without any changes.  If you remove those lines and such a new method was introduced you would have to go back through all of the child classes adding them back in before your final class would work for that method, *with the chance that you would miss one*.

Daft as it sounds doing things properly now is actually future laziness - it only takes you seconds when you are creating a class to make sure everything is initialised - debugging an uninitialised class can take hours.

Answer (score 0):

**First:**
The `__init__` functions are the constructors of the classes, you can read about them [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).

**Second:**
Your code will run without those lines but the question is why and is it ok to remove them?

For example if you remove the following init

```
class UnaryGate(LogicGate): # LogicGate is the superclass

    def __init__(self, n):
        LogicGate.__init__(self, n)
```

The constructor of the super-class `LogicGate` will  be called directly.

**Third:**
Ok, so can we remove the `self.xxx = None`?

```
class BinaryGate(LogicGate):

    def __init__(self, n):
        LogicGate.__init__(self, n)

        self.pinA = None 
        self.pinB = None
```

We could remove those 2 Lines too but consider this code

```
bg = BinaryGate("binaryGate1")
print bg.pinA
```

This would throw an error because `pinA` is undefined.
If you do not remove the `self.pinA = None` in `__init__` the code will run and `None` will be printed.